# Insoluble Group I/ammonium salts

Tags: solubility

Most solubility references (e.g. [this one](http://www5.csudh.edu/oliver/chemdata/solrules.htm)) say that there are "few" insoluble salts of alkali metals.

Are there *any* exceptions?

Comment: Though I don't know the details, some types of uranium ions can precipitate sodium and ammonium cations when added to water as their [respective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_diuranate) [diuranates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_diuranate). If I recall correctly, a qualitative method to identify sodium in aqueous solution is to add [potassium uranyl sulphate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranyl_sulfate) in the absence of any other non-group 1 cations. I'm curious what other insoluble salts exist, especially for the heavier alkalis.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82328/are-there-any-sodium-salts-that-are-insoluble-in-water

Comment: The link given is dead. Please update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lithium carbonate has poor water solubility.  Cesium triphenylcyanoborate is insoluble in water.

Answer (score 1):

They would advertise $\ce{NaBPh4}$ as a reagent to determine $\ce{K+}$ gravimetrically.  Old-timers may remember the feared Kalignost.  $\ce{XBPh4-}$, for X=$\ce{Rb+, Cs+, NH4+,Tl+}$ is similarly insoluble.

Thanksfully, now there is methods like AAS, and we plague the kids with that in Instrumental Analysis/Analytical Chemistry classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest case involving limited (<0.1 molar) solubility is [lithium fluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_fluoride), whose solubility is only about one part in 750 by mass at 25°C (about 0.05 molar).

Answer (score -1):

There are some cations whose Group I/ammonium salts are not soluble in water. For example, (thanks Nicolau) the diuranate of ammonium is insoluble in water.

Additionally, (as I just found) the hydrides (H-) of alkali metals are not soluble, it seems, in any room-temperature liquid solvent. They hydrolyze violently (http://goo.gl/Dl8Bd4), and the hydride ion has never been observed in solution.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's right to say that substances that undergo solvolysis aren't soluble. Technically, they do dissolve, they just react immediately afterwards.