# Are there any sodium salts that are insoluble in water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility

Are there any sodium salts (e.g. NaCl) that are insoluble in water? If so, what are their approximate $K_\mathrm{sp}$ values?

Comment: Quick Google search turns up a couple of examples: [$\ce{NaBiO3}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bismuthate) and [$\ce{NaZn(UO2)3(CH3COO)9}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranyl_zinc_acetate) (tangentially related: for potassium, [$\ce{K(BPh4)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_tetraphenylborate))

Comment: Related (and interesting if you want to know more): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/175694/what-factors-cause-a-few-sodium-salts-to-be-water-insoluble

Answer (score 10):

If your definition of a "sodium salt" is any solid compound that contains monovalent cationic sodium, then all you need to do is to look below your feet. The earth has abundant sodium bearing minerals (aka "salts").

Scroll down in [The Mineralogy of Sodium](https://www.mindat.org/element/Sodium) to where it says *Most widespread minerals containing Sodium*. Out of all of these, only halite is soluble. The rest are mostly insoluble. I'm not sure their *ksp* values will mean anything here, because the dissolution of these minerals is up to kinetics and not thermodynamics at STP.

You can also have a look at [Mineral Species containing Sodium (Na)](http://webmineral.com/chem/Chem-Na.shtml). Other than a few that are soluble (particularly some of the first on the list), the rest are not that soluble. Two reasons for that - they are silicates or phosphates which are in general insoluble, and they have other things in them.

Answer (score 8):

> Sodium tends to form water-soluble compounds such as halides, sulfate, nitrate, carboxylate and carbonates. There are only isolated examples of sodium compounds precipitating from water solution. However, nature provides examples of many insoluble sodium compounds such as the feldspars (aluminum silicates of sodium, potassium and calcium), sodium bismuthate ($\ce{NaBiO3}$), sodium octamolybdate ($\ce{Na2Mo8O25·4H2O}$), sodium thioplatinate ($\ce{Na4Pt3S6}$), sodium uranate ($\ce{Na2UO4}$). Both form of sodium antimonate (meta - $\ce{NaSbO3.7H2O}$, pyro - $\ce{Na2H2Sb2O7.H2O}$) has a solubility 0.7g/L. Sodium metaphosphate, $\ce{NaPO3}$ has both soluble and insoluble form.

**Ref.**: *The Elements*, PediaPress

Comment: Also, sodium fluorosilicate

Comment: So how strong the bonds are that water can't separate the ions!

Answer (score 5):

Cryolite, $\ce{Na3AlF6}$, is one such compound. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryolite

Answer (score 5):

The salt $\ce{NaK2AlF6}$ ("elpasolite") is insoluble. Its exothermic precipitation is used as the basis for the thermometric titrimetric quantitative determination of sodium in a wide range of sample matrices. The determination is fast, accurate and highly precise.