# Insoluble ammonium salts?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, precipitation, salt

Most solubility rules I can find state that "most ammonium salts are highly soluble". I wonder if there are actually any insoluble salts containing the ammonium ion. An answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8663/insoluble-group-i-ammonium-salts) states that ammonium diuranate is insoluble but it is downvoted and I couldn't verify that being true.

 If none of ammonium salts is soluble, can there be other ways of getting rid of ammonium ions in water? That is, precipitation or liberation as NH₃?

Comment: If uranyl salts are not available, ammonium salts are recognized by heating it at high temperature. Mixed with some $\ce{Na2CO3}$, all ammonium salts produce some $\ce{NH3}$ which is a gas recognized by a pH band. It turns out to a basic color in presence of $\ce{NH3}$

Comment: Cation exchange resin in ammonium cycle is quite insoluble.  :-)

Comment: According to the CRC Handbook, of Chemistry and Physics (a *great* place to start looking), **ammonium phosphomolybdate monohydrate** is soluble to 0.02 g/100 ml water (presumably at ~25 °C). That's not *insoluble*, just *slightly soluble*, as far as I'm concerned ;-). Regrettably, though, no data on uranium salts' solubility (classified??),

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Wouldn't adding to water affect hydration level and thus affect solubility? Also, can it be made by precipitation? It is stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_phosphomolybdate) that it can be made by heating ammonium orthomolybdate combined with phosphoric acid and nitric acid, yielding ammonium nitrate, water, and a yellow precipitate of ammonium phosphomolybdate.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 analitical reactions in wich ammonium ion becomes a part of insuluble compound:

$\ce{2NH4+ + Na+ + [Co(NO2)6]^3- -> (NH4)2Na[Co(NO2)6](s)}$
$\ce{NH4+ + 2[HgI4]^2- +4OH- -> [O=Hg2=NH2]I(s) + 7I- + 3H2O}$
$\ce{NH4+ + Mg^2+ + HPO4^2- -> MgNH4PO4(s) + H+}$